# Optimisation when state evaluation is costly.

Tags: optimization

Looking for advice on constrained optimization problem. Currently I construct a Lagrangian and use various descent algorithms, line searches, all the usual tricks. No matter what I use, I am limited by a very costly state-evaluation step.

Is there an optimization algorithm that I can implement to avoid state evaluation unless required?

Comment: Can you calculate gradients and/or hessian?

Comment: I can, but only finite difference, so again it is costly.

Comment: If evaluating the objective function is expensive, then optimization will be expensive. I don't see how one can make it cheap.

Comment: If you can't calculate gradients (finite differences doesnt count), then the best choice for you is simplex method

Comment: Why is the evaluation expensive?